# Prevent Application Window from Going Translucent when Moved or Resized

Tags: windows-10

Here is a screenshot of a browser window on my machine:

[image: Browser Screenshot]

When I drag it around, it goes translucent, like this:

[image: Translucent Browser Screenshot]

**Is there a way to change Windows 10 to not do this?**

(FYI: I want to get rid of it because I have an issue where this translucent state remains after I am done dragging it.)

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and include a screenshot of the registry editor that displays the keys associated with **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize**

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

1. Turn Transparency OFF in Windows Settings.

Start, Settings, enter Dark Mode in the search box, go the setting and turn Transparency OFF. See the screen shot below.

[image]

2. Update your Video Driver and (if Laptop or if you have one) Chipset driver as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is incorrect, I left transparency effects on:

[image]

And I never observed the behavior mentioned above.

Instead I changed this:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `sysdm.cpl`>><kbd>Enter</kbd>

To open "System Properties" (Task Manager process name: `Change Computer Settings`, window name: `System Properties`, true name: `SystemPropertiesComputerName.exe`)

[image]

Click "Advanced" to open "Advanced System Settings" process, window name: `System Properties`, true name: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` (note if you get to the page by clicking in GUI, the `Name` and `Command line` shown by taskmgr.exe wouldn't change, however if you type its true name directly, you will directly get to the page and the name and command will be its, and it won't change when you click other tabs, same applies to below):

[image]

Then click "Performance">>"Settings" to open `Change Computer Performance Settings`, `Performance Options`, `SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe`

So to directly open the page you need:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `systempropertiesperformance`>><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Click "Adjust for best performance">>click <kbd>Apply</kbd>>>click <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

I believe the behavior you mentioned is disabled by disabling "Show window contents while dragging"

Alternatively, if you hate all those unnecessary GUI clicks like me, use this:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `cmd`>><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To open elevated cmd(I just pin "Administrator: Command Prompt" to taskbar, it is very easy)

Then paste this:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects /v VisualFXSetting /t REG_DWORD /d 2
```

(And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

It does the same thing the above mentioned GUI method does, and without all those clicks...

I don't know for sure whether it will solve your problem or not, but it is very likely to help, I just want to help.